# Reactjs Axios PUT empty data

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, forms

So i'm trying to make an add order page form which should submit data into the user's orders[] collection (mongoDB).

The backend works just fine and does exactly what it is meant to do, but the frontend form just submits empty data although the request status is 200.

**This is the form**

```
export default function OrderForm() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('')
    const [ticker, setTicker] = useState('')
    const [amount, setAmount] = useState('')
    const [price, setPrice] = useState('')
    const [date, setDate] = useState('')
    const [comments, setComments] = useState('')

    const handleSubmit = async(value) =>{
        value.preventDefault()

        const orders = {
            ticker: ticker,
            amount: amount,
            price: price,
            date: date,
            comments: comments
        }

        console.log(orders)

        try{
            axios.put(`http://localhost:8081/api/auth/order/:email?=${email}`, {
                data: orders
            })
            .then((res) => {
                if(res){
                    console.log(res)
                    console.log(`Order saved to ${email}'s account`)

                }
            }).catch(e =>{
                console.log(e)
            })

        }catch(error){
            console.error(error)
        }
    }
```

**The form outputs this:**
[Console log of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8Lgi.png)

**This is the backend code which works when i test it with Postman:**

```
exports.addOrder = async (req, res) => {

  const {email} = req.params

  const {
    ticker,
    amount,
    price,
    date,
    comments

  } = req.body;

  try{
    const user = await User.findOneAndUpdate({
      email: email
    }, {
      $push: {
        orders: {
          ticker: ticker,
          amount: amount,
          price: price,
          date: date,
          comments: comments

        }
      },
    })

    if (!user) {
      console.log('Sorry that user does not exist')
    }

    res.status(200).send(user).json({
      message: `Order: ${orders} \n has been added to ${user}`
    });

  }catch(error) {
    res.status(400).json({
      error: error.message
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using url as `http://localhost:8081/api/auth/order/:email?=${email}`, You have to use `http://localhost:8081/api/auth/order/${email}`

For more information: (https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters)

Comment: Thanks, yeah I figured it out. But thanks for the input. I hope this helps someone